# Monitoring : Tivoli performance viewer embedded on websphere 8.5.5 has stopped few minutes after

Tags: jvm, websphere, monitoring, tivoli

Do you know how I can parameter the tivoli performance viewer embedded on websphere so that it won't stop monitoring few minutes after ?

I have enable the logging of the JVM Performance module and I saw that it stopped few minutes after...

Please tell me how to enable 24 hours monitoring.

(Websphere -> monitoring and tuning -> performance viewer -> current activity)

Regards
Thanks a lot
Fatiha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you specified in the Log settings section?
(Websphere -> monitoring and tuning -> performance viewer -> current activity -> server1 -> Settings -> Log.

This should determine how long you log your PMI data for?

Comment: Thank you user6808564 ! It's what I was looking for, the duration parameter, thanks a lot !